# Rails 3 - Search, HABTM and Caterogizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the Advanced Search Form from RailsCasts (#111), but I want to add the possibity to search in subcategories with a collection check boxes.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # post_id, food_id, pet_id
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, name
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, name
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, title.
```

In my search.rb model, I tried :

```
posts = posts.where(food_ids: food_ids) if food_ids.present?
```

I created a new model called : Subcategorysearch.rb, exactly the same as Categoty.rb, but it only for the search request. Inside I have: post_id, food_id, pet_id.

With or without the new model, I always get :

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Searches#show 
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.food_ids

Thanks by advance.

**EDIT**:

When I create a new post, the Subcategories aren't going in the Post table, but in the Category table. I need to make the Post search working with the possibility of filtering with a collection check boxes the subcategories.

**EDIT 2**

I tried a lot a things, but I think I'm kind of lost.

The "real" problem, is to perform a search engine like the Railscasts #111 - Advanced Search Form and using something like the Railscasts #17 - HABTML Checkboxes, with the "categorizations".

The final result I need, is, for exemple: Search a Post and be able to filter the result with checkboxes collection :

```
Post tile = My first post
Food = Name 1
Pet = Name 2
```

...

And then, only show the Posts that contains the Title like "My first post", Food like "Name 1" or by ID, and the same for Pet.

Again, thank you by advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `food_ids` instead of `food_id` in your where clause key.
As you can understand from the error, posts table does not have a food_ids column, it has a food_id column.

Try:

```
posts = posts.where(food_id: food_ids) if food_ids.present?
```

Comment: Same error, exept : no such column: posts.food_id, insted of no such column: posts.food_ids (just the 'S'). Post table doesn't have food_id column to, it's in the Category table.

Comment: @rthbound: Why? The records are in the Category table, not in the Post table. Anyway, I tried to add the column, and it didn't find any record, because it's stocked in the Category table.

Comment: so if the column is in the table "categories", why are you looking for it in the "posts" table?

Comment: @rthbound: Because I don't know how to search in 2 differents tables and display it as one search result. I thought It was like creating it, but it seems different...